# How can I have Idris automatically prove that two values are not equal?

Tags: proof, idris

How can I have Idris automatically prove that two values are not equal?

```
p : Not (Int = String)
p = \Refl impossible
```

How can I have Idris automatically generate this proof? `auto` does not appear to be capable of proving statements involving `Not`. My end goal is to have Idris automatically prove that all elements in a vector are unique and that two vectors are disjoint.

```
namespace IsSet
    data IsSet : List t -> Type where
        Nil : IsSet []
        (::) : All (\a => Not (a = x)) xs -> IsSet xs -> IsSet (x :: xs)

namespace Disjoint
    data Disjoint : List t -> List t -> Type where
        Nil : Disjoint [] ys
        (::) : All (\a => Not (a = x)) ys -> Disjoint xs ys -> Disjoint (x :: xs) ys

f : (xs : List Type) -> (ys: List Type) -> {p1 : IsSet xs} -> {p2 : IsSet ys} -> {p3 : Disjoint xs ys} -> ()
f _ _ = ()

q : ()
q = f ['f1, 'f2] ['f3, 'f4]
```

Comment: I think it may be possible by using default arguments with a custom script to find the proofs. You'd have to write the type of f as `f: (xs: List Type) -> (ys: List Type) -> {default (%runElab prfFinder) p1: IsSet xs} -> {default (%runElab prfFinder) p2: IsSet ys} -> {default (%runElab prfFinder) p3: Disjoint xs ys} -> ()` where `prfFinder: Elab ()`. But I don't know how the value of prfFinder looks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using %hint I got Idris to auto prove any NotEq it encountered. Since Not (a = b) is a function (since Not a is a -> Void), I needed to make NotEq (since auto cannot prove functions).

```
module Main

import Data.Vect
import Data.Vect.Quantifiers

%default total

fromFalse : (d : Dec p) -> {auto isFalse : decAsBool d = False} -> Not p
fromFalse (Yes _) {isFalse = Refl} impossible
fromFalse (No contra) = contra

data NotEq : a -> a -> Type where
    MkNotEq : {a : t} -> {b : t} -> Not (a = b) -> NotEq a b

%hint
notEq : DecEq t => {a : t} -> {b : t} -> {auto isFalse : decAsBool (decEq a b) = False} -> NotEq a b
notEq = MkNotEq (fromFalse (decEq _ _))

NotElem : k -> Vect n k -> Type
NotElem a xs = All (\x => NotEq a x) xs

q : (a : lbl) -> (b : Vect n lbl) -> {auto p : NotElem a b} -> ()
q _ _ = ()

w : ()
w = q "a" ["b","c"]
```